# C command line arguments with Windows.h

Tags: c, windows

I'm making a simple window program in C with `windows.h` (I'm quite new to this).
As I understand, a start of execution is function `int WINAPI WinMain`. If I make `int main` function, the window does not show. So,

1. Is there a way to have `int main` and `int WINAPI WinMain` at the same time?
2. If not, how do I get command-line arguments?

P.S. I'm using Windows.

Comment: Why do you need to make *one* program and not two? Two programs could share a common library (e.g. DLL)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Some background**

The actual entry for the program is the start-up code.

The start-up code does not have any arguments.

The start-up code then calls `main` or `WinMain`.

... so the start-up code must "calculate" the arguments of `main` or `WinMain`.

**About your question**

You cannot use `main` and `WinMain` at the same time.

However, you can "calculate" the arguments of `main` or `WinMain` the same way the start-up code does it:

- `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` is used to get the program instance (first argument of the `WinMain` function)
- The "command line" argument of `WinMain` is calculated from the value returned by `GetCommandLine()`
- This value is also used to calculate `argv` and `argc` of `main`
- The window show mode argument of `WinMain` is calculated from the `STARTUPINFO` which is read using `GetStartupInfo()`
- The environment variables passed to `main` are returned by `GetEnvironmentStrings()`

Comment: [`CommandLineToArgvW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw) could also help, for `main` in particular.